# How to remove old multi turn water inlet valve

Tags: water, toilet, valve

I was replacing some of the parts in my toilet and noticed the grommet on the toilet end of the supply hose is worn and started to leak when I reconnected it.  My preference would be to just replace the grommet but I can't find a replacement grommet part so it looks like I am stuck replacing the water shutoff valve.  But I can't tell on this one how to remove it.  I don't see any threads and believe it might be soldered on.  Unfortunately the valve is right up against the Escutcheon ring. Does anyone have any suggestions on where to find grommets for old style metal flex lines or how to remove the valve?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

that is a compression fitting,the nut is against the wall plate.using 2 pairs of adjustable wrenches,use 1 wrench to hold the valve(holding the valve just under the outlet hose)use the other wrench to loosen the nut.when done the valve will pop off leaving the nut and a brass ferrule.carefully remove the ferrule with pliers(wary not to crush the pipe,grip the ferrule and twist back and forth while putting pressure in a forward,pipe opening,direction)remove the nut,then replace with new valve as above,in reverse